# Wave equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: wave-equation

I am trying to find the displacement $u(r,t)$ in a circular membrane of radius $5$, that is clamped down along the circumference. If the initial displacement is $f(r)$ and the membrane is released from rest.

$$a^2\left(\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}\right) + \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{du}{dr}\right)=\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}$$

Where $\frac{du}{dt}(r,0)=0,\quad u(5,t)=0, \quad u(r,0)=f(r)$

Transforming the boundary conditions is what throws me off.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.